# Card Reader Not working when published on IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis, cardreader

I'm developing a .NET MVC website that requires the users to fill in their information. Locally (localhost using visual studio) I am using a card reader to get the user information from their citizen cards. The problem arouse when tryied to publish the software in IIS.

I can't access the card reader.... :< How can i overcome this situation without using applets ? Is Javascript a viable option?

Comment: Make sure you are reading the card from the user PC and not from the IIS Server.

Comment: Depends. What Card Reader are you using?

Comment: It really depends on which kind of card reader you use. Most vendors don't support such devices in IIS applications.